# Managing a list in umbraco 5

Tags: list, dynamic, umbraco

I have recently started working on an umbraco 5 project and am finding it a bit of a struggle compared with umbraco 4. What I am trying to do is have a list of items that are managed in the content section of the site where users can add items to a list, this list is then used in drop downs and page categories throughout the site.

I am looking for the best way to do this, I am currently part way through creating a property editor that manages a list of text boxes but not sure if this is the best way of doing it, and  Im currently not entirely sure of how to go about doing even this. I can save one property no problem, but a dynamic list?

Can anybody give me some idea of how they would go about doing this with some code examples, theres not a huge amount of resources for 5 out there at the minute.

Many thanks to those who contribute.

UPDATE

I have now copied the multiple textstring property editor from the source code and am looking to update it to have an extra text input. Its using the knockout javascript library of which Im not too familar with, below is the code I have so far, does anyone know how I would update this to save both text values to the database?

```
<ul class="relatedlinks-textstring-inputs" data-bind="template: { name: 'textstringRow', foreach: textstrings }"></ul>

<script id="textstringRow" type="text/html">
<li style='width: 250px;'>Name<input type="text" data-bind="value: value" />Url<input type="text" data-bind="value: value" /></li>
</script>
@Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Value, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-bind", "value: value" } })
```

Comment: How many items will be on this list? and how often would this list need to change. Is it just a list? or a list of key/value pairs?

Comment: There will probably be a max of around 7 items on the list, it would be a list where each item is 2 text boxes, one for the name and one for the url. I wanted to do something fancy like the multiple textstring property editor but have given up now as my deadline looms so have just added 14 textboxes in a new tab as a short term solution.